# Arduino only executing one set of if-else

Tags: arduino, robotics, motordriver

This code if for a simple robot car.
I'm trying to control the robot with 4 geared motors and L289 driver and standard RC Tx/Rx.

I have used some print statements to debug any errors.

When I try to move the robot forward/backward, I can see serial monitor printing froward/backward, but the robot doesn't move.

When I try to move if left/right it works fine. On commenting the left-right moving statements in code the robot does move forward and backward but fails to do so with all the if else statements uncommented.
Here's the code.

```
//Receiver pin
byte CH1_PIN = 9;
byte CH2_PIN = 10;

//Motor driver pins
int left_motor_pin1 = 4;
int left_motor_pin2 = 5;
int right_motor_pin1 = 6;
int right_motor_pin2 = 7;
void setup() {
  
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(CH1_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(CH2_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(left_motor_pin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(left_motor_pin2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(right_motor_pin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(right_motor_pin2, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(left_motor_pin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(left_motor_pin2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(right_motor_pin1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(right_motor_pin2, LOW);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  int ch_1 = pulseIn(CH1_PIN, HIGH);
  int ch_2 = pulseIn(CH2_PIN, HIGH);


  drive(ch_1, ch_2);
  delay(5);

}


void drive(int move_left_right, int move_fwd_back) {


  // Set direction for moving forward

  if ( move_fwd_back > 1700 ) {
    digitalWrite(left_motor_pin1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(left_motor_pin2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(right_motor_pin1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(right_motor_pin2, LOW);
    Serial.println("forward");
  }
  // Set direction for moving backwards.
  else if (move_fwd_back < 1300) {
    digitalWrite(left_motor_pin1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(left_motor_pin2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(right_motor_pin1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(right_motor_pin2, HIGH);
    Serial.println("reverse");
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(left_motor_pin1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(left_motor_pin2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(right_motor_pin1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(right_motor_pin2, LOW);
    Serial.println("NONE");
  }

  // Set direction for moving left
  if ( move_left_right < 1300 ) {
    digitalWrite(left_motor_pin1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(left_motor_pin2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(right_motor_pin1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(right_motor_pin2, HIGH);
    Serial.println("left");
  }
  
  //set directionfor moving right
  else if (move_left_right > 1700) {
    digitalWrite(left_motor_pin1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(left_motor_pin2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(right_motor_pin1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(right_motor_pin2, LOW);
    Serial.println("right");
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(left_motor_pin1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(left_motor_pin2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(right_motor_pin1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(right_motor_pin2, LOW);
    Serial.println("NONE");
  }


}
```

Comment: both inputs control both outputs. so if one input stops both outputs, nothing happens.

Comment: @Juraj can you please elaborate a bit. And how can I improve the code to make it work

Comment: I don't know. But I would start with a table (on paper or Excel) with inputs as header and first column and fill in the required outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have two `if-else` conditions - both changing the same outputs. So the 2nd `if-else` condition will always override what the 1st one has done.

eg. if you want the motor to just move forward, the code would set the motors to both move forward - however, immediately afterwards, the code decides there is no left/right input so sets the motors to stop. This is so fast you don't see any movement in the motors.

To start with, I would change the code so that the decision regarding the left/right input is inside the else condition of the forward/backward condition. This would give the forward/backward input priority over the left/right input.

i.e.

```
if ( move_fwd_back > 1700 ) {
    digitalWrite(left_motor_pin1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(left_motor_pin2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(right_motor_pin1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(right_motor_pin2, LOW);
    Serial.println("forward");
}
// Set direction for moving backwards.
else if (move_fwd_back < 1300) {
    digitalWrite(left_motor_pin1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(left_motor_pin2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(right_motor_pin1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(right_motor_pin2, HIGH);
    Serial.println("reverse");
}
else {
    // Set direction for moving left
    if ( move_left_right < 1300 ) {
        digitalWrite(left_motor_pin1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(left_motor_pin2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(right_motor_pin1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(right_motor_pin2, HIGH);
        Serial.println("left");
    }
    //set directionfor moving right
    else if (move_left_right > 1700) {
        digitalWrite(left_motor_pin1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(left_motor_pin2, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(right_motor_pin1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(right_motor_pin2, LOW);
        Serial.println("right");
    }
    else {
        digitalWrite(left_motor_pin1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(left_motor_pin2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(right_motor_pin1, LOW);
        digitalWrite(right_motor_pin2, LOW);
        Serial.println("NONE");
    }
}
```

Comment: now it can only turn if it stops

Comment: True - it does need some enhancing to get better control - but I think my answer does explain the immediate problem the OP was facing and a way to progress.

Comment: It actually does the job. I know there are tiny bits to polish but since it's moving perfectly, I can work on improving it. Thank you very much for your help